# Sinch iOS Call did not establish

Tags: ios, sinch

I am trying to build a simple app to app calling in iOS using Sinch.

Lets say I have node a and b. Node a calls node b. Node b gets in coming call as the incoming call method of CallClientDelegate is called and call progress function at node a is called.

Node b picks up the call. I am working with simulator so its understandable voice not being transmitted. But still when node b picks ups the call Call did establish method of CallDelegate should be called. I am writing NSLog in it.

But its not being called. And time of total calls in since dashboard is still 0hours 0 minutes 0 seconds.

Comment: Are you the same person that mailed in to support?

Comment: Is this resolved for you, what was the outcome?

Comment: @cjensen i have the same problem, I have those three delegate methods, progress, established, didEnd and none is being triggered... what's to be done ?

Comment: Most likely you you dont have live delegate on sinch client, it needs to be held in a var that lives the whole applicaiton life cycle. Tryu and NSLog on sinch client on didStop. and also try to see if listener is an instance when you expect a call.

Comment: @cjensen - While my app is in background , some times delegate method for SINCall is not triggered. can you help me with this.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati either mail in to support or ask a specific question you self on here on SO, you cant hijack someone elses question.